# How to display an image in angular from asp.net core

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm building a project in angular 6 and asp.net core. I have an images saved on the server, and I save the image path and image name in the db.

I've tried passing the image path to angular after using domSanitizer but the browser still says "Not allowed to load local resource: {filepath}"

component.ts

```
photo: Photo;
imageToShow: any;

getPhoto() {
    this.fileService.getPhoto().subscribe(response => {
      this.photo = response;
      this.imageToShow = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.photo.thumbPhotoPath);
    });
  }
```

component.html

```
<img [src]="imageToShow">
```

service.ts

```
getPhoto(id: number) {
      return this.http.get<Photo>(this.baseUrl + 'get-photo/' + id);
  }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet("get-photo/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPhoto(int id) 
{
    var photo = await _repo.GetPhoto(id);

    var pathToImage = Path.Combine(photo.ThumbPhotoPath, photo.ImageName);

    FilePhoto photoData = new FilePhoto()
    {   
        Id = photo.Id,
        ThumbPhotoPath = pathToImage,
    };
    return Ok(photoData);
}
```

Does anyone know the best way to display the image stored on the server to angular? Should I be passing it back as a blob instead? and if so what would be the best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: return from the API the file to the angular https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794275/return-jpeg-image-from-asp-net-core-webapi

Comment: What is the value for `photoData`? If you access the `photoData.ThumbPhotoPath` directly from web browser, will it show the image correctly? Share us the generated html for `<img [src]="imageToShow">`. Where did you save the image?

Comment: @TaoZhou the value for photoData is just the photo id and the path to the photo on the server. The image is saved in the wwwroot on the .net core api, and I want to display that image in the angular app.

Comment: @TaoZhou  The console in the browser has the error "IMAGE PATH: SafeValue must use [property]=binding: C:\Users\{rest of the image path} "and "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/ {the rest of image path}". I was passing that path into the [src] on the image.

Comment: @TiagoSilva I'll try this as well. Do you know what the component on the angular side would look like?

Comment: What is the value for `imageToShow`? You should combine your path with web site root url and file path in the `wwwroot`. Check [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2)